# urllib3.urlencode googlescholar url from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I am trying to encode a string to `url` to search google scholar, soon to realize, `urlencode` is not provided in `urllib3`.

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> string = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?" + urllib3.urlencode( {"q":"rudra banerjee"} )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlencode'
```

So, I checked [urllib3 doc](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#module-urllib3.request) and found, I possibly need `request_encode_url`. But I have no experience in using that and failed.

```
>>> string = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?" +"rudra banerjee"
>>> url = urllib3.request_encode_url('POST',string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request_encode_url'
```

So, how I can encode a string to url?

**NB** I don't have any particular fascination to urllib3. so, any other module will also do.

Answer (score 2):

(**Edit:** I assumed you wanted to download the URL, not simply encode it. My mistake. I'll leave this answer as a reference for others, but see the other answer for encoding a URL.)

If you pass a dictionary into `fields`, urllib3 will take care of encoding it for you. First, you'll need to instantiate a pool for your connections. Here's a full example:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

r = http.request('POST', 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar', fields={"q":"rudra banerjee"})
print(r.data)
```

Calling `.request(...)` will take care of figuring out the encoding for you based on the method.

Getting started examples are here: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#usage

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. but here `r` is <class `'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>`. but I need to open the url in `webbrowser` module, as url. while trying, getting error:
`TypeError: Can't convert 'HTTPResponse' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Ah I see, you don't want to _download_ the website, you just want to encode the URL. I'll add a separate answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

To simply encode fields in a URL, you can use `urllib.urlencode`.

In Python 2, this should do the trick:

```
import urllib
s = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?" + urllib.urlencode({"q":"rudra banerjee"})
print(s)
# Prints: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=rudra+banerjee
```

In Python 3, it lives under `urllib.parse.urlencode` instead.